# Mathjax not working on firebase uploaded html document

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, mathjax

I am developing an online physics app, I used firebase for uploading HTML document. Mathjax works well for local file. But when I upload it to firbase does not work. Please help me.
Here is my page code:

```html
<!-- Copyright Arnab Maiti -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
// This code is required for inline rendering. 
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [ ['$','$'] ],
      processEscapes: true
     
    }
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Handlee" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/physis-project.appspot.com/o/Daily%20Physics%2Fstyles.css?alt=media&token=e8427689-7842-4cf1-a4fe-88503d905499" >
</head>
<body>
<h1>Dimensional analysis 1</h1>
<div class="section">
<h3>Units</h3>
Every Physical entities that are measureable are called <b>Physical quantity.</b> To measure there should have a certain systym. To define every measurement as
a specific type and of specific scale. That is <B>Unit</B>. Different physical quantity has different units. For example time has a unit of second, length has a unit of meter, volume has a unit of $m^3$ etc.
The unit gives the concept of the quantity type. There is a prefix system to scale a measurement. As if you use to gram to use your weight (say 56500 gram) sounds horrible! Every measurement has a suitable scale.<br>
See the chart<br>
<table width=100% align="center" border=3 bordercolor="teal">
<tr align="center">
<th>Prefix</th><th>Scale</th>
</tr>
<tr align="center">
<td>mili (m)</td><td>$10^{-3}$</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center">
<td>micro ($\mu$)</td><td>$10^{-6}$</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center">
<td>nano (n)</td><td>$10^{-9}$</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center">
<td>pico (p)</td><td>$10^{-12}$</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center">
<td>femto (fm)</td><td>$10^{-15}$</td>
</tr>

<tr align="center">
<td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="center">
<td>Mega (M)</td><td>$10^3$</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center">
<td>Giga (G)</td><td>$10^6$</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center">
<td>Tera (T)</td><td>$10^9$</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center">
<td>Peta (P)</td><td>$10^{12}$</td>
</tr>

</table>
There are seven fundamental units:<br>
mass (g), length (m), time (s), Electric current (A), Temperature (K), Amount of substance (mol), Luminous intensity (cd).
<br>All other units are derived from this seven units. <br>
<br><br>
<h3>Dimensions</h3>
Dimestion of a physical quantity is the relationships between the seven fundamental quantities. <br>
here is some examples:<br>
Volume=$(length)^3=[L^3]$<br>
Charge=(Electric current) x (time of charge flow)$= It=[I][T]=[IT]$<br>
Density=$\cfrac{Mass}{volume}=\cfrac{[M]}{[L^3]}=[ML^{-3}]$<br>
Similarly, velocity=$[LT^{-1}]$, acceleration=$[LT^{-2}]$, Force=$[MLT^{-2}]$ etc. We will know more dimensions along course.
<br><br>
<b>Checking an Equation dimensionally</b>
<div class="question">
If a particle moves wiith constant acceleration ($a$), the change of displacement ($s$) with time ($t$) is given by the equation: $$s=ut+\cfrac 12 at^2$$ where $u$ is initial velocity.
</div>
<div class="solution">Consider LHS,<br> the dimension of $s$ (position) $=dim(s)=[L]$<br>
Consider RHS,<br>$dim(ut)=dim(u).dim(t)=[LT^{-1}][T]=[L]$<br>
Again, $dim(\frac 12 at^2)=dim(at^2)$<br> $=dim(a).dim(t^2)=[LT^{-2}][T^2]=[L]$<br>
So, $dim(s)=dim(ut)=dim(\frac 12 at^2)$. Hence the equation is dimensionally correct.
</div>
<b><i>Here $dim()$ stands for dimension of</i></b><br><br>
<div class="discussion">
<b>Points to remember</b><br>
<ul>
<li>Constants like 1, 5, 1/3, a, b have no dimension (or dimension$=1$)</li>
<li>All constants are not dimensionless. For example Gravitational constant (G) has dimension</li>
<li>Trigonometric, logarithomic, exponential functions are dimensionless. For example, $\sin{\omega t}$, $e^{\omega t}$ has no dimension. So here $dim(\omega t)=1$</li>
<li>For an equation to be dimensionally correct each combination in the either side should have same dimension</li>
</ul>
</div>
<br><br><hr>
<h1>Introductory Calculus</h1>
This part introduces primary calculus needed for the course. It does not introduces any typical concept. If you know this simply ignore.<br>
<h3>Limts</h3>In many cases we need to work with approximations. If you add 0.1 to 10,000,000, it seems to be useless as you will not see any change. So you can simply ignore the '0.1' or treat it as zero.
This can be comparable with real world application : donating 1 dollar to a billionary (Let say Bill Gates).<br>Now think it in a different way. The 10,000,000 looks like infinity to 0.1, (suppose you give 1 billion dollar to a person who never seen more than 1 dollar).<br>
Here lies the first conclusion.<br>
$$\lim_{x\to 0}x=0$$ $$\lim_{x\to \infty}x=\infty$$
the upper symbol read as <b>'limit x tends to zero (or infinity)'</b>
Remember x tends to zero ($x\to 0$) stands for smaller number than you imagine also $x\to\infty$ stands for a higher  number than what you can imagine<br><br>
<b>Formulas</b><br>
1) $\lim_{x\to 0} x^n=0$<br><br>
2) $\lim_{x\to \infty}x^n=\infty$<br><br>
3) $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac xx=1$ (It may sounds like 0/0 !)<br><br>
4) $\lim_{x\to a}\cfrac {x^n -a^n}{x-a}=na^{n-1}$<br><br>
5) $\lim_{x\to 0}\cfrac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$
<br><br>
</div>
<c>Author- Arnab Maiti,  Copyright:MEDevsLtd</c>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my document link https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/physis-project.appspot.com/o/Daily%20Physics%2FLearn%20Data%2F01.html?alt=media&token=bfc13a4f-dd0d-46a7-9890-2aa9fcddaae4

Comment: Don't know why mathjax is not running online. But it works well when kept as local file

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61146721/browser-blocking-mathjax-on-app-engine-static-page/61156257#61156257 including the note on the outdated MathJax version.

Comment: Thanks a lot @PeterKrautzberger ..It worked!